# Is there a way to upgrade my existing ships?

Tags: stellaris

I just completed the research for Coilguns and would like to upgrade my existing fleet for a damage boost. However, I'm not seeing an option for this anywhere. The only avenue I'm seeing is to design a new ship that uses Coilguns and build some of those. But if I have to keep incrementally upgrading tech and buying all new ships, then doing that again when I research the next level of tech, that seems horribly inefficient and I might want to simply wait for a few techs and batch them up in the new ship design.

However, if there is a way to partially upgrade already existing ships, that would be a huge benefit. I see an "Upgrade Fleet" option, but it is greyed out.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So to upgrade your fleet you first need to update the ship design, you can go into the ship designer in the top left and add the Coilguns. What I think you may have done wrong is created a new ship design and added the Coilguns there instead of updating your current Papillon-class Corvettes. When you change your ship design make sure you are modifying the Papillon-Class corvette and not creating a new class.

If you want to change the name of the class you can do that in the ship building screen, if you create a new class it won't change the existing class. Once you have update the Papillon-class and/or renamed it the upgrade fleet button should be Colored.

Comment: Is that all you have to do? Like, if I have a fleet of ships on the opposite end of the galaxy and then update their design, will those ships be upgraded? Or do I need to bring that fleet home?

Comment: They'll have to go to one of your spaceports to do the upgrade.

Comment: @cbirdsong is Correct. You have to go to one of your own or vassals space port to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Right click in your home world with the ship selected and there will be a message to upgrade the fleet to the latest designs.